# Creating pandas dataframe from json file; getting memory error

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I'm trying to read a json file into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_json('output.json',orient='index')
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc 
in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, 
convert_dates,keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)
196         if exists:
197             with open(filepath_or_buffer, 'r') as fh:
--> 198                 json = fh.read()
199         else:
200             json = filepath_or_buffer

MemoryError:
```

I've also tried reading it using gzip:

```
def parse(path):
  g = gzip.open(path, 'rb')
  for l in g:
  yield eval(l)

def getDF(path):
 i = 0
 df = {}

 for d in parse(path):
   df[i] = d
   i +=1
   #if i == 10000: break ## hack for local testing

 return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df,orient='index')

 pathname ='./output.json.gz'
 df = getDF(pathname)
```

But get a segmentation fault. How can I read in a json file (or json.gz) that's this large?

The head of the json file looks like this:

{"reviewerID": "ARMDSTEI0Z7YW", "asin": "0077614992", "reviewerName": "dodo", "helpful": [0, 0], "unixReviewTime": 1360886400, "reviewText": "This book was a requirement for a college class. It was okay to use although it wasn't used much for my particular class", "overall": 5.0, "reviewTime": "02 15, 2013", "summary": "great"}
{"reviewerID": "A3FYN0SZYWN74", "asin": "0615208479", "reviewerName": "Marilyn Mitzel", "helpful": [0, 0], "unixReviewTime": 1228089600, "reviewText": "This is a great gift for anyone who wants to hang on to what they've got or get back what they've lost. I bought it for my 77 year old mom who had a stroke and myself.I'm 55 and like many of us at that age my memory started slipping. You know how it goes. Can't remember where I put my keys, can't remember names and forget about numbers. As a medical reporter I was researching the importance of exercising the brain. I heard about BrainAerobics and that it can help improve and even restore memory. I had nothing to lose, nor did mom so we tried it and were actually amazed how well it works.My memory improved pretty quickly. I used to have to write notes to myself about every thing. Not any more. I can remember my grocery list and errands without writing it all down. I can even remember phone numbers now. You have to keep doing it. Just like going to the gym for your body several times a week, you must do the same for your brain.But it's a lot of fun and gives you a new sense of confidence because you just feel a lot sharper. On top of your game so to speak.That's important in this competitive world today to keep up with the younger one's in the work force.  As for mom, her stroke was over two years ago and we thought she would never regain any more brain power but her mind continues to improve. We've noticed a big difference in just the last few months since she has been doing the BrainAerobics program regularly. She's hooked on it and we are believers.Marilyn Mitzel/Aventura, FL", "overall": 5.0, "reviewTime": "12 1, 2008", "summary": "AMAZING HOW QUICKLY IT WORKS!"}
{"reviewerID": "A2J0WRZSAAHUAP", "asin": "0615269990", "reviewerName": "icu-rn", "helpful": [0, 0], "unixReviewTime": 1396742400, "reviewText": "Very helpful in learning about different disease processes and easy to understand. You do not have to be a med student to play. Also you can play alone or with several players", "overall": 5.0, "reviewTime": "04 6, 2014", "summary": "Must have"}

---

---

Comment: What error are you getting? How does your 'output.json' look?

Comment: I've added what the json file head looks like. The error is a MemoryError. Do I need to read it in "chunks?" If so, how would I do this.

Comment: Are there line endings between the reviews in the json file?

Comment: Yes. One review per line.

Comment: Do you want to take some action for each review, or do something that requires using all of the reviews at once?

Comment: I will eventually want to analyze each review using NLP. But for now just want to load them into a dataframe.